# How to use ', pattern = ' to select files from a list of possible suffixes

Tags: r, file, pattern-matching

I have 20'000 1minute wav files recorded over two weeks in a folder. These are all named with a suffix to indicate the time of day they were recorded (e.g "_213032" = 9:30pm and 32 seconds). I want to work on a smaller subset of these recorded at certain times of day (once every 20 minutes between 7pm and 5am). So I created a vector of the appropriate suffixes (**file_name_ends**) and saved all the file names I want into a vector (**wav_files**) using:

```
vector_of_files = file_name_ends[,1]
wav_files = vector()
for(i in 1:length(vector_of_files)){
  wav_files = c(wav_files, dir(path, pattern = vector_of_files[i]))
}
```

I then read in these wav files during a loop:

```
filenames = vector()
for_AR = vector()
for( i in 1:length(wav_files)){
  filenames = c(filenames,(wav_files[i])) #add the file name to empty list
  load_file = readWave(wav_files[i]) #select the wave file being iterated upon
  for_AR = c(for_AR, load_file)}
```

This component works well for other functions I need to run on this files in this loop. But, I now want to run the **AR** function from the **seewave** package on only the 470 .wav files that match one of these file names in the large folder of 20'000 files. I have attempted many variants similar to the following without success:

```
 ARvalues = AR(for_AR, datatype = "object", pattern = wav_files)
 #or 
 ARvalues = AR(path, datatype = "files", pattern = vector_of_files)
```

I suspect the key is in the correct use of the 'pattern = ' component of this function with one of my vectors?

In case this helps:

```
head(file_name_ends)
       V1
1 _190002
2 _192002
3 _194002
4 _200002
5 _202002
6 _204002

head(vector_of_files)
[1] "_190002" "_192002" "_194002" "_200002" "_202002" "_204002"

head(wav_files)
[1] "20210209_192002.WAV" "20210209_194002.WAV" "20210209_200002.WAV" "20210209_202002.WAV"

head(for_AR) #practicing on four files for now
[[1]]

Wave Object
    Number of Samples:      2784000
    Duration (seconds):     58
    Samplingrate (Hertz):   48000
    Channels (Mono/Stereo): Mono
    PCM (integer format):   TRUE
    Bit (8/16/24/32/64):    16 


[[2]]

Wave Object
    Number of Samples:      2784000
    Duration (seconds):     58
    Samplingrate (Hertz):   48000
    Channels (Mono/Stereo): Mono
    PCM (integer format):   TRUE
    Bit (8/16/24/32/64):    16 


[[3]]

Wave Object
    Number of Samples:      2784000
    Duration (seconds):     58
    Samplingrate (Hertz):   48000
    Channels (Mono/Stereo): Mono
    PCM (integer format):   TRUE
    Bit (8/16/24/32/64):    16 


[[4]]

Wave Object
    Number of Samples:      2784000
    Duration (seconds):     58
    Samplingrate (Hertz):   48000
    Channels (Mono/Stereo): Mono
    PCM (integer format):   TRUE
    Bit (8/16/24/32/64):    16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `AR` function with `do.call`.

```
library(seewave)
result <- do.call(AR, for_AR)
result
```